# Type Error in Attempting to Create Pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas

I'm attempting to calculate a score in a pandas data frame and populate a new pandas series with the output.

I have a column/series called "Dialogue" and I want to calculate a sentiment analysis for each cell in this column score using a sentiment analysis tool I found called `afinn` that would be formatted like this: `afinn.score('insert_text_here')`. I thought this would be as easy as writing `season_1['Sentiment'] = afinn.score(scripts['Dialogue'])` but I get this error: `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`.

I'm confused because the type of the data is exactly the type I'd expect to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) for apply function for each value of `Dialogue` column:

```
season_1['Sentiment'] = scripts['Dialogue'].apply(afinn.score)
```

What should working same like lambda function:

```
season_1['Sentiment'] = scripts['Dialogue'].apply(lambda x: afinn.score(x))
```

Comment: Yo! Thanks for the fast response. That first line worked yes. You're awesome. What do you mean by your second line?

Comment: @NathanCahn - second line is alternative solution, working same way. Maybe better readable.